# Change cursor over <option> tags?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Is there any way to change the cursor when hovering over an item in a `<select>` combobox? I assumed that doing `option { cursor: pointer; }` in CSS would work, but it doesn't seem to.

Comment: Have you tried `option:hover { cursor: pointer; }`?  Not sure if it will work though.

Comment: @MatthewJohnson that doesn't work either, see my answer.

Comment: I just tried every version of `select|option[:hover] { cursor: pointer }` including some using `*` and nothing changed the way my pointer rendered. Good question!

Comment: @SomeKittensUx2666 Figures, `select` and `file` inputs are always touchy like that I suppose.

Comment: It does seem to work here, but only in Mozilla. And I'm running under KDE. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/XmLqY/2/).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

### **Make your own dropdown**

`<option>` tags are rendered by the operating system, not the browser, so you can't style them.

Instead, make your own dropdown that you can fully control or use a 3rd-party plugin, for example [Bootstrap's Dropdown](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns).

[MSDN says it best](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Except for background-color and color, style settings applied through the style object for the option element are ignored. In addition, style settings applied directly to individual options override those applied to the containing select element as a whole.

[MDN also chimes in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Styling_HTML_forms)

> Some elements simply can't be styled using CSS. These include all advanced user interface widgets such as range, color, or date controls as well as all the dropdown widgets, including `<select>`, `<option>`, `<optgroup>` and `<datalist>` elements. The file picker widget is also known not to be stylable at all. The new `<progress>` and `<meter>` elements also fall in this category.

Comment: Good answer, can you provide a documentation source for the poor folk like myself?

Comment: @ChrisB Found it in MSDN of all places, MDN is mum on the topic.

Comment: Damn. I'll take a look at the Bootstrap link - thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Possible in the following ways

```
select {
    -webkit-appearance:button !important;
        -moz-appearance:button !important;
            appearance:button !important;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Confirmed with the latest version of Chome, Firefox, Edge

Comment: Doesn't work in Firefox.

Answer (score -4):

```html
<html>
<head><title>E</title></head>
<body span style="cursor:crosshair">
I think this is the code
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: The question asks changing the **cursor when hovering over an item in a <select>** which is option.