# How to display multiple spaces in HTML select list <option></option>

Tags: html, css

jsfidder here http://jsfiddle.net/a3LwW/4/

My problem is I have multiple spaces in the content of `<option>`

jQuery `val()` gives me correct value, but browser renders the `<option>` as if there is only a single space in the string.

Is there a way to to render multiple spaces correctly in `<option>`??

I tried `<option><pre>three   spaces</pre></option>`, but it doesn't do what I want.

[image: spaces in select option]

**HTML**

```
<select id="list">
    <option>one space</option>
    <option>two  spaces</option>
    <option>three   spaces</option>
</select>
<p>Current Value:<pre id="val"></pre></p>
```

**JS**

```
function update_val () {
    $('#val').text($('#list').val()); 
}

$('#list').change(update_val);

//init
update_val();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `&nbsp;` (normally you shouldn't use this for spacing, but you [don't have many more options in `<select>` elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22770672/1216976)):

```
<select id="list">
    <option>one space</option>
    <option>two &nbsp;spaces</option>
    <option>three &nbsp;&nbsp;spaces</option>
</select>
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a3LwW/5/)

Comment: Interesting, in fact my data came from backend through ajax, bind to the UI through knockoutjs. I think I can find a way to map a viewable form of the data to the UI. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think You can use native PHP character like `"\xC2\xA0"`.

More characters you can get by PHP function `html_entity_decode`:

```php
$nbsp = html_entity_decode('&nbsp;');
$str = 'Hello' . $nbsp . 'World!';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the whitespace characters other than `&nbsp;` such as `&thinsp;`, `&ensp;`,and `&emsp;`.

Like

```
 <option>three &emsp; spaces</option>
```

Comment: I really need to easy mapping spaces to viewable spaces since in my real app, my data are bound from javascript code. Mapping one space to one `&nbsp;` is all I need. But thanks for the varies of spaces in HTML, I never used them before!