# how to set cursor to pointer when its over select and option?

Tags: html, css, typescript, select, angular9

how to set cursor to pointer when its over select and option?

HTML

```
<div class="form-group" *ngIf="!isHidden">
    <label><b>Empresa:</b></label>
    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedEmpresa" name="idEmpresa" class="form-control" id="idEmpresa">
         <option *ngFor="let empresa of empresas; index as i" [value]="empresa.id">{{ empresa.nome }}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#idEmpresa {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Your best bet is to implement your own DropDown Control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only a few style attributes that can be applied to an  element.  This is because this type of element is an example of a "replaced element". They are OS-dependent and are not part of the HTML/browser. It cannot be styled via CSS.  There are replacement plug-ins/libraries that look like a  but are actually composed of regular HTML elements that CAN be styled.
like as dropdown bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

I found the below answer from StackOverflow only check it once:

Sadly,  tags are rendered by the operating system, not the browser, so you can't style them with cursors. Instead, use a plugin like [Bootstrap's Dropdown.](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns)

[MSDN says it best:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> Except for background-color and color, style settings applied through
> the style object for the option element are ignored. In addition,
> style settings applied directly to individual options override those
> applied to the containing select element as a whole.

[MDN also chimes in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Styling_HTML_forms)

> Some elements simply can't be styled using CSS. These include all
> advanced user interface widgets such as range, color, or date controls
> as well as all the dropdown widgets, including , ,
>
> and  elements. The file picker widget is also
> known not to be stylable at all. The new  and 
> elements also fall in this category.

Comment: Credits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22770672/1136132

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished this by creating a CSS class that is associated with the Select but applied to the Options within that Select. The CSS statements look something like this (with "cursor: pointer;" being the style you're asking about):

```
select.ABC_class option {
    font-size: 16px; 
    text-indent: 25px;
    padding: 5px;
    /* wrap text in compatible browsers */
    -moz-white-space: pre-wrap;
    -o-white-space: pre-wrap;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    /* use an ellipsis to hide text that can't wrap */
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    /* add border after every option */
    border-bottom: 1px solid #38C6F4;
    background: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7);
    color: #0075C9; 
    cursor: pointer; 
}

select.ABC_class option:hover {
    font-size: 20px; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    text-indent: 2px;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
    /* wrap text in compatible browsers */
    -moz-white-space: pre-wrap;
    -o-white-space: pre-wrap;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    /* use an ellipsis to hide text that can't wrap */
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    /* add border after every option */
    border-bottom: 1px solid #38C6F4;
    background-color: #0075C9;
    color: white;
}
```

Here, I've applied/added that class to your Select tag:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedEmpresa" name="idEmpresa" class="form-control, **ABC_class**" id="idEmpresa">
```

In addition to the other styles that the CSS class specifies, your Select Options should then display the pointer cursor.