# How can I change the cursor in the dropdown portion of a select?

Tags: html, css

I have a dropdown that looks like this:

```html
<select style="width: 125px; cursor: pointer;">
  <option>AAAA</option>
  <option>BBBB</option>
  <option>CCCC</option>
</select>
```

The cursor starts out as a pointer.  However, the cursor switches to a default arrow in the dropdown.  How can I make it use a pointer too?

Thank you!

Comment: Interesting. Browsers have different ways of rendering selects.

Comment: Add cursor:pointer on options too

Answer (score 1):

Style the cursor on hover for example

```
select:hover, option:hover {
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some elements simply can't be styled using CSS. These include all advanced user interface widgets such as range, color, or date controls as well as all the dropdown widgets, including , ,  and  elements.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Salil Rajkarnikar
You may add pointer to  tag.

```
<select style="width: 125px; cursor: pointer;">
    <option style="cursor: pointer;">AAAA</option>
    <option style="cursor: pointer;">BBBB</option>
    <option style="cursor: pointer;">CCCC</option> 
</select>
```

or

```
<style>
   select,option{
   cursor: pointer;
   } 
</style>

<select style="width: 125px">
   <option>AAAA</option>
   <option>BBBB</option>
   <option>CCCC</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: I found this link, and it might help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22770603/change-cursor-over-option-tags